# Ayuda para ordenar jquery.datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, symfony2

buen día grupo:
 Tengo problemas con jquery.datatables con symfony, específicamente con la opcion 'order'. Al obtener los objetos que requiero ya vienen ordenados descendetemente en el controller y al desplegar los datos en la Vista únicamente como tabla despliega correctamente descendetemente, mi problema es cuando agrego la funcion datatable:

```
$('#table_info').DataTable();
```

Que inmediatamente me lo vuelve a ordenar ascendentemente, yo ya intenté con opciones como:

```
$('#table_info').DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
} );
```

Incluso también probé desactivando `"ordering": false,`

Pero ninguna opción hace lo que necesito, solo quiero que aparezca el ultimo registro agregado en la primera fila. Agradecería vuestra ayuda. saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de probar de varias maneras, se pudo deducir que cuando inicias el datatable(), su opción sort viene activada por defecto y lo ordena a su criterio la tabla. Considerando eso se pudo solucionar desactivando el sort:

```
$('#data-table').dataTable( 
    {
        "bSort" : false
    });
```

ahora todo funciona correctamente. gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

prueba haciendo una consulta DQL que te mande el array con los datos ordenados descendentemente directo del modelo al controlador.
Ejemplo:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.price > :price')
    ->setParameter('price', '19.99')
    ->orderBy('p.price', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();

$products = $query->getResult();
```

Varios ejemplos bastante claros hay aki: https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/symfony-2-x/capitulo-8/buscando-objetos

Espero sea de tu ayuda